# subset of a nested query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not quite sure what to even search for to address this specific question. 
So here goes...

My current design:

```
User < AR
  has_many :items
  has_many :projects

Project < AR
  has_many :groups

Group < AR
  has_many :items
```

Given a `@project` and a `@user` how do I get Groups for a project (`@project.groups`) but have those Groups only contain `items` for the given @user?

This seems like something that should be taken care of in a model, rather than as controller logic, but I'm not sure what the best Rails way for doing this would be. I've investigated scope and custom finders, but it seems unnecessarily complicated. Perhaps it's a flaw in the relationship between the models.

Edit: Perhaps this helps?

```
User < AR
  has_many :items
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

Project < AR
  has_many :groups
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

Group < AR
  has_many :items
```

Comment: Can a `Group` belong to multiple project? Your question implies that but your model design does not.

Comment: Do you want all Groups that contain items for the Project's owner or for any given user?

Comment: @KandadaBoggu group cannot belong to multiple projects.

Comment: @BrianGlick I'd like all groups for a given project and I would like those groups to only contain items for a given user

Comment: Can a Project belong to multiple users? If a project belongs to only one user than @Kyle's answer should suffice.

Comment: Update your question to add the `belongs_to` relationships in the model.

Comment: I've updated the models, as a project can belong to more than one user.

Comment: What I'd ultimately like to endup with is a @containers variable that I can use in a view to list each container and under each container list the items owned by a certain user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for has_many :through:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :groups, :through => :projects
  has_many :items, :through => :groups
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

Then you can just call:

```
@user.items
```

to get all of the items for a given user.

Note that nested has_many :throughs only work since Rails 3.1; otherwise, you'll probably have to write a method!

Comment: That's actually what I have now, but what I'd like is to still get the collection of groups and have those groups only contain the items associated with a given user rather than all the items that the group may normally contain. I guess I could iterate over @project.groups and repopulate each group's collection of items, but it seems like there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This has a little raw SQL, but should work:

```
def Project
  def groups_for_user u
    self.groups.select("DISTINCT groups.*").join(:items).where("items.user_id = ?,u.id)
  end
end
```

The reason for the `"DISTINCT groups.*"` is to prevent repeats in the result because you're joining the lower level `items` table.

Comment: I'll give this a try today, but it looks like it should work. I got close with .include and .where, but I was missing something. This looks like what I was missing. Will this get a group even if it has no items for the given user in it?

Comment: This should NOT get a group if it has no items for the given user because the join(:items) call creates an INNER JOIN in the SQL.